# Не могу запустить службу неявным вызовом

Tags: android, activity, android-intent, service, intent-filter

```
//Activity
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final String ACTION = "com.example.app.service_onstartcommand.MyService";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onclick(View view) { ;
    startService(new Intent(ACTION));
}
}

//Service
public class MyService extends Service {

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand");
    loadFlags(flags);
    new Thread(new MyRun(startId)).start();
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

void loadFlags(int flags) {
    if (flags == START_FLAG_REDELIVERY)
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "START_FLAG_REDELIVERY");
    if (flags == START_FLAG_RETRY)
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "START_FLAG_RETRY");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


class MyRun implements Runnable {

    int startId;

    public MyRun(int startId) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyRun#" + startId + " create");
        this.startId = startId;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyRun#" + startId + " start");
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stop();
    }

    void stop() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyRun#" + startId + " end, stopSelfResult(" + startId + ") = " + stopSelfResult(startId));
    }
}
}

//Manifest
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.app.service_onstartcommand">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".MyService"
        android:process=":newproc"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.app.service_onstartcommand.MyService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
</manifest>
```

//stackTrace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.app.service_onstartcommand, PID: 3012
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.example.app.service_onstartcommand.MyService }
    at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1682)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1711)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1695)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:515)
    at com.example.app.service_onstartcommand.MainActivity.onclick(MainActivity.java:20)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте указать пакет `intent`'a:

```
intent.setPackage(getPackageName());
```

т.е. в вашем случае запуск сервиса должен происходить так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION);
intent.setPackage(getPackageName());
startService(intent);
```

либо явно указать сервис:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
startService(intent);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло